# Printing Image with Bluetooth Printer in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to print the screenshot image of **first** page in Flutter. So far I have come up to the part where I need to parse that image into function that would print it, here is the code:

**FIRST PAGE**

```
_screenshot() {
screenshotController.capture().then((File image) {
  //Capture Done
  setState(() {
    _screenshot = image;
  });
  print('Successful Screenshot => $_screenshot');
  Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Print(_screenshot)));}
```

So this is the page that screenshots that whole page and pushes that screenshot to the second screen. Here is the second screen:

**SECOND PAGE**

```
 class Print extends StatefulWidget {

  final File screenshot;

  Print(this.screenshot);

  @override
  _PrintState createState() => _PrintState();
}
```

Here I initialize that image from the first page, and then I created the function for printing that should print the ticket, but I am getting an error:

```
Future<Ticket> _ticket(PaperSize paper) async {
final ticket = Ticket(paper);


//this is a working option, but I don't want to load from assets, but load screenshot file from first page
//final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(assets/store.png');

final File img = await rootBundle.load(widget.screenshot); //here parse the image from first page **ERROR HERE**
final Uint8List bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
final Image image = decodeImage(bytes);
ticket.image(image);

return ticket;
}
```

I am getting an error that **Byte data cannot be assigned to variable type File** which I understand, but how would I go around making this work? I am using the **esc_pos_bluetooth: ^0.2.8** library for bluetooth printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to load data from `rootBundle` instead, you can use `readAsBytes()` class method from `File` class which returns `Uint8List`.

```dart
Uint8List bytes = await widget.screenshot.readAsBytes();
```

Your final code should look like.

```dart
  Future<Ticket> _ticket(PaperSize paper) async {
  final ticket = Ticket(paper);

  final Uint8List bytes = await widget.screenshot.readAsBytes();
  final Image image = decodeImage(bytes);
  ticket.image(image);

  return ticket;
}
```

Comment: readasbytes() didn't work since it returns a future, so I added `final Uint8List bytes = widget.screenshot.readAsBytesSync();`, and that seems to not throw errors, I still can't test it out, but hopefully that works.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add `await` keyword now I updated the answer.